# Need Tkinter Help: Trying to get text entered into entries to print in console when buttons are pressed. I cannot get it to print

Tags: python, tkinter, graph, python-class

The goal of this project is to have a user be able to enter a m and b value into a tkinter window and have a graph show up when a button is pressed. There is multiple windows. There is a click to start button, and a menu to select the type of graph. Currently I am just focusing on getting the linear graph working. When the linear window is reached it prompts the user to enter a m and b value (through entries).

[image: Window Here]

When the graph button is pressed I have coded for it to print the m and b value out. As of right now I cannot get it to print out in the console. If anyone could help up let me know thanks!

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

class testInputs():
    def __init__(self,m,b):
        #self.displaygframe = Frame(root)
        #self.displayglabe = Label(self.displaygframe,
                                  #text="Test for now",
                                  #font= "ComicSansMS 14")
        print(m)
        print(b)
        
        

class selectGraph(): #2
    def __init__(self):
        self.gselectframe = Frame(root)
        self.gselectlabel = Label(self.gselectframe,
                                  text = "Select Graph Type",
                                  font= "ComicSansMS 14")
        
        
        self.Var = IntVar()
        
        #define buttons
        self.linearButton = Radiobutton(self.gselectframe,
                                        text="Linear",
                                        variable = self.Var,
                                        value=1)
        
        self.quadraticButton = Radiobutton(self.gselectframe,text="Quadratic",
                                           variable = self.Var, 
                                           value = 2)
             
        
        self.confirmButton = Button(self.gselectframe, text = "Continue", command = self.transferAnswer,
                                    fg = "red", font = "ComicSansMS 14",
                                    bd = 2, bg = "light green")
        
        
        self.sgBack = Button(self.gselectframe, text = "Back", command = self.backButton,
                             fg = "red", font = "ComicSansMS 5",
                             bd = 2, bg = "light green")      
        
        
        #pack 
        self.gselectlabel.pack()
        self.linearButton.pack(anchor=W)
        self.quadraticButton.pack(anchor=W)   
        self.confirmButton.pack()
        self.gselectframe.pack()
        

        mainloop()
    def transferAnswer(self):
        answer= self.Var.get()
        print(str(answer))
        self.gselectframe.destroy()
        getEquation(answer)
        
    def backButton(self):
        self.gselectframe.destroy()
        introWindow()
        
class getEquation(): #3
    def __init__(self, answer):
        if answer == 1:
            self.linearInput()
            
        if answer == 2:
            self.quadraticInput()
            
        else:
            selectGraph()
            
    def linearInput(self):
        self.linearFrame = Frame(root)
        
        #define widgets
        self.linearLabel = Label(self.linearFrame,
                                  text = "Enter Linear Equation",
                                  font= "ComicSansMS 14")
        
        
        self.linearBack = Button(self.linearFrame, text = "Back", command = self.backButtonLinear,
                             fg = "red", font = "ComicSansMS 5",
                             bd = 2, bg = "light green")
        
        
        formatLabel = Label(self.linearFrame,
                                  text="Format:",
                                  font="ComicSansMS 14")
        
        equationLabel = Label(self.linearFrame,
                              text="y=mx+b",
                              font="ComicSansMS 14",
                              fg="midnight blue")
        
        #name = StringVar()
        #name2 = StringVar()
        
        self.mLabel = Label(self.linearFrame,
                            text= "m=",
                            font= "ComicSansMS 14")
        
        self.mInput = Entry(self.linearFrame,
                            width =2, font="ComicSansMS 14")
        
        self.bLabel = Label(self.linearFrame,
                            text = "b=",
                            font = "ComicSansMs 14")
        self.bInput = Entry(self.linearFrame,
                            width=2,
                            font="ComicSansMS 14")
        #get info from widget
        m = self.mInput.get()
        b = self.mInput.get()        
        
        self.graphButton = Button(self.linearFrame, text = "Graph", command = self.nextFromLinear(m,b),  #error from here
                                fg = "red", font = "ComicSansMS 14",
                                bd = 2, bg = "light green")

    
        
        #place widgets on screen
        #self.linearFrame.pack()
        
        self.linearLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)
        formatLabel.grid(row=1,column=0)
        equationLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
        
        
        self.bInput.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.bLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)
        
        
        self.mInput.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.mLabel.grid(row=3,column= 0)
        
        self.graphButton.grid(row=5, column=1) #error from here
        
        self.linearBack.grid(row=5,column=0)
        

        self.linearFrame.pack()
        
        
        mainloop()
        
        
    def quadraticInput(self):
        self.quadraticFrame = Frame(root)
        self.quadraticLabel = Label(self.quadraticFrame,
                                  text = "Enter Quadratic Equation",
                                  font= "ComicSansMS 14")
        self.quadraticLabel.pack()
        
        
        self.quadraticBack = Button(self.quadraticFrame, text = "Back", command = self.backButtonQuadratic,
                             fg = "red", font = "ComicSansMS 5",
                             bd = 2, bg = "light green")                
        
        self.quadraticBack.pack(anchor=SW)
        self.quadraticFrame.pack()
        mainloop()
        
        
    def backButtonLinear(self):
        self.linearFrame.destroy()
        selectGraph()
        
    def backButtonQuadratic(self):
        self.quadraticFrame.destroy()
        selectGraph()
        
    def nextFromLinear(self,m,b):
        
        #self.linearFrame.destroy()
        #testInputs(m,b)
        print(m)
        print(b)
        
        
    #Figuring out how to write singular back button function for all equation Frames:
    #def backButton(self, frame1):
        #frame1.destroy()
        #selectGraph
        
class introWindow(): #1
    def __init__(self):
        self.introframe = Frame(root)
        self.introlabel = Label(self.introframe,
                                text = "Graphing Program",font="ComicSansMS 14")
        self.introbutton = Button(self.introframe, text = "Click to start", command = self.windowRemoval,
                fg = "red", font = "ComicSansMS 14",
                bd = 2, bg = "light green")
        
        self.introlabel.pack()
        self.introbutton.pack()
        self.introframe.pack()
        
        
        mainloop()
    def windowRemoval(self):
        self.introframe.destroy()
        selectGraph()
        
introWindow()
```

Comment: There's way too much code here, and you haven't made it clear which part is the problem. Remove the code that's unrelated to the problem.

Comment: The `command` argument needs to be a function reference, not a function call.

Answer (score 0):

The `command` argument to `Button()` must be a function reference, not a call to the function. You're calling the function when you create the button, not when it's clicked.

Use a `lambda` to create an anonymous function. And it has to call `get()` when it's called, you can't call it when creating the button, or you'll get the initial values of the inputs, not what the user has entered into them.

```
    self.graphButton = Button(self.linearFrame, text = "Graph", 
                            command = lambda: self.nextFromLinear(self.mInput.get(),self.bInput.get()),  #error from here
                            fg = "red", font = "ComicSansMS 14",
                            bd = 2, bg = "light green")
```